# table tooltip css

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have generated a **dynamic table** from asp.net code behind page and adding *Table.ToolTip* value. How to add table.tooltip style?

```
tbl = new Table(); tbl.ID = "tblstatus";
tbl.Style.Add("border-collapse", "collapse"); 
tbl.ToolTip = "tool tip message";
```

Comment: By style, do you mean the appearance of the tooltip?

Comment: yes, I have to change Table.ToolTip border style.

Answer (score 0):

The `ToolTip` property is rendered as an [HTML `title` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.3). Browsers generally display this as a tooltip, which doesn't support styling.

If you want rich popup-on-hover content, look into something like [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/).